# Do Python thread names reflect the number of open threads?

Tags: python, python-multithreading

If I see a stack trace like the following:

```
Exception in thread Thread-101:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  (...)
```

Does "Thread-101" necessarily mean that there are 101 active / open / performance-decreasing threads?  Or do those names work like IDs in a database, where the number always goes up, even if older records (threads) are deleted (closed)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.name

> A string used for identification purposes only. It has no semantics.
>   Multiple threads may be given the same name. The initial name is set by the constructor.

In addition, just to humor yourself, you can try this

```
>>> from threading import Thread
>>> t1 = Thread()
>>> t1
<Thread(Thread-1, initial)>
>>> t2 = Thread()
>>> t2
<Thread(Thread-2, initial)>
>>> t2.setName('Thread-1')
>>> t2
<Thread(Thread-1, initial)>
>>> t1
<Thread(Thread-1, initial)>
>>> t1.name
'Thread-1'
>>> t2.name
'Thread-1'
```

You can see that I have named both threads to the same name, so thread names being an index of any sort goes out the window.

Comment: Is there any tool where these names who up for monitoring? for example, htop/ps doesn't seem to know about them.